# Show accounts that have a missing value from a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with accounts and payment type. Every account MUST have 1 payment type of 'GOGW', 1 account may have multiple payment types.

I need to find a way to identify which accounts don't have a 'GOGW' please

table1

| Account | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | Cheque |
| 123456 | GOGW |
| 654321 | Direct Debit |
| 654321 | GOGW |
| 987654 | Direct Debit |
| 456789 | BACS |

should return

| Account | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 987654 | Direct Debit |
| 456789 | BACS |

Comment: Look at using `exists`

Comment: Why in the output you want to have the Type? Whether "GOGW" is missing or not, has nothing to do with the Type that you want in the output, only with the Account.

Comment: Do you have separate tables of all accounts and all payment types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY / HAVING to find out which accounts that does not have any GOGW

```
SELECT Account
FROM table1
GROUP BY Account
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'GOGW' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

If you want to find those that does not have exactly one:

```
SELECT Account
FROM table1
GROUP BY Account
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'GOGW' THEN 1 END) <> 1
```

Now you can use IN, EXISTS or a JOIN to get the types for these accounts:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN (
    SELECT Account
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY Account
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'GOGW' THEN 1 END) = 0
) AS t2
    ON t1.Account = t2.Account
```

If you are on a decently recent version, you can use a window function instead:

```
select Account, Type
from ( 
  select Account, Type, COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'GOGW' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT) as cnt
  from table1
) as t
WHERE cnt = 0;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e7waLFcT)

Comment: Thank you very much, first time i've used this forum, you guys are ace! I have exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following statement ...

```
SELECT table1.[Account]
      ,table1.[Type]
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT table1.[Account]
FROM table1
WHERE table1.[Type] = 'GOGW') GOGW ON table1.[Account] = GOGW.[Account]
WHERE table1.[Type] <> 'GOGW'
AND GOGW.[Account] IS NULL
```